# 404 error page not showing

Tags: asp.net

I've got this in my web.config and it's being hosted by the DiscountASP.net ISP

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx"/>
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="404.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
```

I am hosting the site on DiscountASP.net and they also tell you to config it this way.  I'm using Enterprise Library but I don't think that should make a difference.  I don't believe I need to config anythign for a 404 in EL.

When my page loads with an error, my 404.aspx doesn't show and I get the default custom errors off message.   I do not know why I don't get my 404.aspx page showing and get this instead:

Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

Comment: Does a 404 hit when you go to a page that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a relative path to see if that makes a difference?

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
```

Alternately, try an absolute path:

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="http://www.domain.com/errors/404.aspx"/>
```

**EDIT:** As others have pointed out, and based on your comment to another answer, the 404 error page should be displayed when someone navigates to a page that doesn't exist, whereas general errors on a page could be captured by the defaultRedirect. So if you're testing the 404 then make sure you're testing with a nonexistent page. To test the defaultRedirect then have one of your pages throw an exception etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are overriding this in another web.config, say in a sub folder?  Or we can go the other way. Are you sure this is in the application root?

Comment: no, I actually deleted all files and re-uploaded it to the ISP.  Only one web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you don't want to use the defaultRedirect for 500 errors?

Comment: in fact I specified just as a test the 404.aspx for the defaultRedirect (I know it's not in my post here but I tried it) and it made no diff.  I still don't see any erorr page regardless.

Comment: When the YSOD (Yellow screen of death) appears do you see response code as 500 in tamper data / fiddler?

Comment: I want to show a friendly error page on any .aspx runtime errors

Comment: ah, ok so even when I specify the defaultRedirect, it's still not hitting my page.

Answer (score 0):

You are FTP-ing the files correct?  Try uploading the file as a binary file instead of text. You might be suffering from an encoding problem.  I'm willing to bet right now that nothing you are doing in your web.config is working.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/net-141/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-page-statuscode-404-throws-500-a-663415.html).
The real catch was using this:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```